# elasticsearch query - two criteria

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I have a list of JSON files in elasticsearch.

I have a list of strings, `matching` which I want to use as the criteria for a search.

Where, `matching = ["223232_ds","dnjsnsd_22","2ee2i33","mkddsj2220","23e3efdjn"`

I now need to find those records in elasticsearch where two keys contain values in this list, `matching`.

Without elasticsearch and simply loading the JSON as a python object I can do this like:

```
results= []
for record in JSON_list:
   if record['key_1'] in matching and record['key_2'] in matching:
            results.append(record)
```

Where the `JSON_list` looks like this:

```
[{'key_1' : "blahaksds",
'key_2' : "njasdnjkns"},
{'key_1' : "bladfgfdf",
'key_2' : "njasdsfsdrr"}]
```

How do I search for multiple criteria in es? Previously, I've used this setup to search for a record_id directly.

```
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch()

name = "so_sample"

# Formulate query
query = str("_id:"+'"'+ record_id +'"')

# Query
result = es.search(name,q=query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with two [terms queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-terms-query.html) in the must clause, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "key_1": ["223232_ds","dnjsnsd_22","2ee2i33","mkddsj2220","23e3efdjn"]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "key_2": ["223232_ds","dnjsnsd_22","2ee2i33","mkddsj2220","23e3efdjn"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```